# PDO PHP Connection, Fatal Error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My Connection Class;firstcode.php

```
class DB_functions {
    public $db;
    function __construct() {
        try{
            $db = new PDO("mysql:localhost;dbname=xxx;charset=utf8","xxx","xxx");
            echo 'Connected';
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            print $e->getMessage();
            echo "No Connection";
        }
    }
    function __destruct() {}

    public function test(){
        
        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM User", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($query->rowCount()){
            foreach ($query as $row) {
                print_r($row);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

My test PHP File;

```
 <?php

require_once('firstcode.php');

$db = new db_functions();

$t = $db->test();

?>
```

And the error I got;

> Notice: Undefined variable: db in firstcode.php on line 20
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in firstcode.php on line 20

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there. In your class, you need to change each iteration of `$db` with:

```
$this->db
```

So your class would look like this:

```
class DB_functions {
    public $db;
    function __construct() {
        try{
            $this->db = new PDO("mysql:localhost;dbname=xxx;charset=utf8","xxx","xxx");
            echo 'Connected';
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            print $e->getMessage();
            echo "No Connection";
        }
    }
    function __destruct() {}

    public function test(){

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM User", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($query->rowCount()){
            foreach ($query as $row) {
                print_r($row);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

<sup>*As you're referencing the internal class variable. It's only accessible within the class scope and is referenced through `$this`.*</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much, This solved all the problems:) I want to ask another one, now I got this error about rowCount() ---> Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-objec

Comment: Usually means it's failing, it will return a PDO Object on success and false on error: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Comment: Thank you, now I doesn't give any error, but somehow it returns blank page, no results appear

Comment: @InfoUnfollowers You'll need to check if the query ran successfully. in your `if($query->rowCount()){` add an `else { print_r($this->db->errorInfo()); }` and see if an error message pops up.